# Java List, Keep First Item, Remove Second Duplicate

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list from a legacy system. Its in a List. Sometimes it may have duplicates.

How do I remove second duplicate (or multiple) while keeping first one? For example, keep 3-furniture and remove 3-TV. Removal is based on alphabetization.

| ProductId | ProductTitle | ProductDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | used for driving |
| 2 | book | reading books |
| 3 | furniture | home decorations |
| 3 | TV | TV entertainment |
| 4 | jewelry | fashion item |

```
@Data
public class Product {
    private long productId;
    private String productTitle;
    private String productDescription;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "based on alphabetization"? Do you want to keep the first one sharing the same ProductId based on their ProductTitle alphabetical ascending sort?

Comment: based on productTitle alphabetization, keep 3-f, remove 3t,  cc @NikolasCharalambidis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in two steps.

1. Group to a `Map` where the `productId` is a key and the product with the lowest alphabetical `productTitle` using `Collectors.maxBy` as a downstream collector.

   ```
   Map<Long, Optional<Product>> productMap = products.stream().collect(
       Collectors.groupingBy(
           Product::getProductId,
           Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Product::getProductTitle))));

   productMap.forEach((id, opt) -> System.out.println(id + " = " + opt));
   ```

   > ```
   > 1 = Optional[Product(productId=1, productTitle=car, productDescription=used for driving)]
   > 2 = Optional[Product(productId=2, productTitle=book, productDescription=reading books)]
   > 3 = Optional[Product(productId=3, productTitle=furniture, productDescription=home decorations)]
   > 4 = Optional[Product(productId=4, productTitle=jewelry, productDescription=fashion item)]
   > ```
2. Extract each `Product` from `Optional` in the `Map` values to a new `List<Product>`.

   ```
   List<Product> filteredProducts = productMap.values().stream()
       .filter(Optional::isPresent)
       .map(Optional::get)
       .toList();

   filteredProducts.forEach(System.out::println);
   ```

   > ```
   > Product(productId=1, productTitle=car, productDescription=used for driving)
   > Product(productId=2, productTitle=book, productDescription=reading books)
   > Product(productId=3, productTitle=furniture, productDescription=home decorations)
   > Product(productId=4, productTitle=jewelry, productDescription=fashion item)
   > ```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can easily do it in Java with `PriorityQueue` and time complexity is `O(nlogn)`

```
    public static List<Product> filterProduct(List<Product> products) {
        PriorityQueue<Product> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> {
            if (a.getProductId() == b.getProductId()) {
                return a.getProductTitle().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.getProductTitle().toLowerCase());
            }

            return Long.compare(a.getProductId(), b.getProductId());
        });

        pq.addAll(products);

        Set<Long> existingIds = new HashSet<>();

        List<Product> res = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            Product product = pq.poll();
            if (!existingIds.contains(product.getProductId())) {
                res.add(product);
                existingIds.add(product.getProductId());
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```